# How do I list only modified buffers in vim?

Tags: buffers

Sometimes when there are a lot of buffers, it becomes hard to see which buffers have been modified using `:ls`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
:ls +
```

See [`:help :ls`](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#%3Als), you'll see it takes an optional "flags" argument, one of which is:

> `[flags]` can be a combination of the following characters, which restrict the buffers to be listed:
>
> - `+`: modified buffers

Answer (score 3):

`:ls +` shows all modified buffers